# users unable to view security log in event viewer

Tags: windows-server-2003, eventviewer

I want to create a user account who is able to view the security log in event viewer, but not as a administrator, just as a power user. I had been getting this error when I click the security log:

`Unable to complete the operation on "Security". A required privilege is not held by the client.`

The method I tried after some Googling:

- Add both user account and computer account in:

  `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Local Policies/User Rights:
  Manage auditing and security log`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you should be able to edit the event log security settings with a little registry or group policy magic and SDDL.  It's a bit hard to summarize, but Microsoft has a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=323076) that tells you what to do.

The most direct way is directly in the registry, in which case you need to edit the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security\CustomSD and specify the SDDL that does what you want.

Searching around is probably the best way to learn SDDL.  I have found [this article](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/jorge/archive/2008/03/26/parsing-sddl-strings.aspx) to be useful.

Comment: +1 - SDDL is annoying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

The above is helpful (very - I was looking for the SID/abbreviation for EVERYONE - which now i know = WD).

OP: The best way to do it is to create a new local group and get the SID for that group, then give the SID read access in the above registry:

(A;;0x1;;;[SID-HERE])

To test that this will work, try giving everyone READ access first:

(A;;0x1;;;WD)

Then change the WD to the SID of the user/group you create.