# Trying to delete an object from the local group policy editor on a windows 2003 r2 member server in a domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows-event-log

I've used this [Serverfault Article](https://serverfault.com/questions/161394/users-unable-to-view-security-log-in-event-viewer) in order to add additional event logs for some webservices to the local group policy on my interfaces server.
For 2 objects i added, i had a mistype and it created 2 logs (check the image) which are unusable and i would like to delete them as it is a production server.
Is that possible?
[image]

Thanks
Itai

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PowerShell 2.0, you can use the [Remove-EventLog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347725.aspx) cmdlet to delete the 2 logs you don't want any more.

```
Remove-EventLog -LogName incorrectlogname -ComputerName servername
```

Comment: I have access to powershell 2.0 on my computer but the server which holds the log i want to remove doesn't have powershell at all, will it still be possible to do it?

Comment: You can run from your local computer and it should remove the logs on the server no problem.

Comment: Where do i get the log name? is that the same as the policy name?
I tried it with the policy name and with the name from the sceregvl.inf file but it keeps saying it's unable to find a log with that name on the server.
by the way, the log i want to remove is a duplicate which i created with the wrong path to the registry, if for example we're talking about the first red circle i marked there, if you look 1 line above you'll see it's the same log, one is operating correctly (and i need him) and the one circled is a corrupt duplicate which i'd like to remove